# Conversão errada de string para double

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho em meu `app.config` o seguinte codigo:

```
<add key="FolhaA4" value="0.168056514197457, 6.36413684210526"/>
```

E aqui o método para pegar esses valores da chave:

```
 private double[] ObterValoresConfiguracao(string chave)
 {
     Manager.Configuration config = Manager.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
     Manager.AppSettingsSection app = (Manager.AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");

     string[] valor = app.Settings[chave].Value.Split(',');
     return valor.Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i)).ToArray();
  }
```

Estou recuperando eles como string e convertendo para `double`, só que preciso que esses valores sejam `doubles` da mesma forma como estão, e na conversão está retornando valores totalmente diferentes.

Ex: `6.36413684210526` converte para -> `6364136842105.26`

Alguém sabe o por que disto? como faço para converter o número para `double` que ele permaneça da mesma forma?

Comment: Tem certeza de que esses valores estão indo certo para o `.Select()`? [Fiz um Fiddle com eles](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76377/convers%C3%A3o-errada-de-string-para-double).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que seu filde não está funcionando não.

Comment: Já tentou converter pra Decimal?

Comment: Fazendo o que está na resposta abaixo funciono. só colocar o `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois a cultura que está utilizando não considera o ponto como separador decimal (PT-BR). Para que isso não ocorra, você deve definir uma cultura que considere. Pode utilizar como exemplo o código abaixo.

```
 return valor.Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
```