# Como converter string para double sem erro de arredondamento?

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo, double

Porque o seguinte comando:

```
Convert.ToDouble("199998,99")
```

Resulta em:

> 199998.98999999999

Já o comando:

```
Convert.ToDouble("199998,98")
```

Resulta em:

> 199998.98000000001

?

Comment: O problema esta no retorno da conversao de string para double em alguns casos.
Por exemplo 
Convert.ToDouble("199998,99") resulta 199998.98999999999
Convert.ToDouble("199998,98") resulta 199998.98000000001

Comment: Talvez esta [questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76377/convers%C3%A3o-errada-de-string-para-double) seja relacionada

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Assumindo que a [cultura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) esteja certa e possa usar a vírgula (parece que sim), o problema é de arredondamento numérico do tipo `double`. Infelizmente a maioria dos programadores não entendem seu o uso e não sabem que ele [não pode ser usado para exatidão numérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), não pode ser usado para valores monetários.

Para resolver isto utilize o tipo [`decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ele não tem esse problema. Ele tem menos performance mas a diferença é pequena ou nula na maioria das situações.

Tem várias perguntas sobre isto aqui com artigos *linkados* para dar mais detalhes. Ninguém deveria programar em cima de valores monetários ou outros que precisam do valor exato sem entender completamente todas implicações.

Isto vale para qualquer linguagem. É uma característica do processador. O tipo `double`, ou mesmo `float` utiliza a forma binária para representar o número e isto impede que ele represente todos os números com casas decimais. Não há nada que se possa fazer. Alguns programadores acham que encontraram a solução. Mas cientistas da computação dois mais renomados já gastaram bastante tempo com isto, já tentaram de tudo e não existe uma solução a não ser usar outro tipo de dado que consiga a representação exata.

Lugares começar:

- [Pergunta sobre C#/SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/101).
- [Pergunta sobre C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101).
- [Pergunta sobre MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101).
- [Pergunta sobre cultura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44957/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Desconhecia isso, vou guardar pra quando precisar. Muito bom.

Comment: Eu sei disso, muito obrigado por salientar, porem tenho que alterar um trecho de código onde nao se pode alterar o tipo de variavel, aparentemente eles utilizam o Double para tudo.

Comment: Não há solução real sem alterar o tipo da variável, se o tipo de está errado, ele precisa ser resolvido. Eu poderia dizer para você usar o `decimal` de forma intermediária e depois voltar para o `double`. Aí o problema aconteceria. Mudando em cálculos intermediários podem reduzir o problema, mas nem sei se deveria. Pode dar a sensação que está melhor e erro é erro. Erros a gente corrige. E este é bem grave. Se não quer corrigir, tenho dó de quem vai usar esta aplicação. Não nada mais que possa ser feito a não ser, pelo menos avisar os usuários que todos os valores não são confiáveis.