# Método não mostra corretamente o resultado esperado

Tags: java, tipagem, valor-monetário

Tenho essa interface

```
public interface Promocional {

    boolean aplicaDesconto(double porcentagem);
    
    default boolean aplicaDescontoDe10Porcento() {
        return aplicaDesconto(0.1);
    }
}
```

A classe `LivroFisico` que estende a superclasse `Livro` e implementa a interface `Promocional`

```
public class LivroFisico  extends Livro implements Promocional{
    public LivroFisico(Autor autor) {
        super(autor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean aplicaDesconto(double porcentagem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

E aqui no método `main` ele não exibe corretamente.

#### main()

```
LivroFisico fisico = new LivroFisico(autor);
fisico.setValor(59.90);
if(fisico.aplicaDescontoDe10Porcento()) {
        System.out.println("Valor agora e: " + fisico.getValor());
    }
```

Ele exibe 59.90 e não 53.91 que é o valor com desconto.

Creio que na classe `LivroFisico` que é obrigatório o uso do método, esteja dando erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas.

O seu problema é recorrente hoje em dia. A maioria das pessoas aprendem a programar por métodos que eu não entendo. Parece ser uma coisa de seguir receitas e não aprender os conceitos, o funcionamento do que está usando. Mesmo estando cheio de informação sobre isto em livros, tutoriais, blogs, e mesmo aqui em diversas perguntas. Eu mesmo [respondi há algumas horas sobre C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77592/101), mas o problema vale para todas as linguagens. É só seguir **todos** os *links* para ir aprendendo sobre o assunto.

A resposta mais específica em Java está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101).

Resumindo: o processador para ter melhor performance trata os tipos de dados `float` e `double` de forma binária e por isso não consegue representar todos os números com casas decimais, há o chamado problema de arredondamento e não tem nada que se possa fazer a respeito a não ser usar o tipo correto de dados quando se lida com valores monetários ou que represente outra coisa que precise de exatidão. Este tipo é o `Bigdecimal`.

Além disto o seu método de desconto (`aplicaDesconto()`) não está fazendo nenhuma operação. Ele não calcula desconto algum.

Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: Desculpa pelo incômodo.

Comment: +1 pelo "*Parece ser uma coisa de seguir receitas e não aprender os conceitos*" =D

Comment: O tipo é `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é verdade, me confundo com o C# ;)

Comment: Só achei muita conversa pra pouca questão. A utilização do tipo não está relacionado com o a questão em si.

Comment: @AndréHenriques ou você resolve os problemas existentes ou continuará com problema. Fica evidente que que as pessoas cometem muito este erro. A outra resposta por exemplo, ensina a fazer coisa errada. Acho que você acha isto bom. Eu não acho e em geral as pessoas aqui não acham. Ensinar errado é sempre algo ruim. Mas você pode responder do seu jeito e ver se o AP muda a aceitação para a sua. Me parece que ele aprendeu alguma coisa com isto. Alguns gostam de aprender o certo, outros preferem fazer de qualquer jeito.

Comment: @Bigown,  essa informação de tipo foi muito boa, mas ela se aplica a comentário e não a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira rápida e simples de resolver isso é alterar seu método aplicadesconto assim:

```
public boolean aplicaDesconto(double porcentagem) {
        setValor(getValor() - (getValor()*porcentagem))
        return true;
    }
```

Isso fará com que ele faça de fato a multiplicação do valor.
Lembre-se de criar os gets e sets de valor.

```
public Double getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(Double valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
```