# Criar herança de classes

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Estou estudando programação em Java orientada a objeto e preciso efetuar o seguinte exercício:

Implemente a classe `Funcionario` e a classe `Gerente`.

1. Crie a classe `Assistente`, que também é um `Funcionario`, e que possui um número de
   matrícula (faça o método `GET`). Sobrescreva o método `exibeDados()`.
2. Sabendo que os Assistentes Técnicos possuem um bônus salarial e que os
   Assistentes Administrativos possuem um turno (dia ou noite) e um adicional
   noturno, crie as classes `Tecnico` e `Administrativo`.

Eu criei o seguinte código:

```
public class Funcionario {
    String nome;
    String cpf;
    double salario;
    int matricula;

    public void exibeDados(){
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome  + " Cpf: " + cpf + " Salário: " + salario + " Matricula: " + matricula);
    }   
}


    public class Gerente extends Funcionario {
        String departamento;
    }

    public class Assistente extends Funcionario{

        public void getMatricula(int matricula){
            this.matricula = matricula;
        }

        public void exibeDados(){
            System.out.println("Nome: " + nome  + " Cpf: " + cpf + " Salário: " + salario + " Matricula: " + this.matricula);
        }
    }


public class Administrativo extends Assistente {
    String turno;

    public void adicionalNoturno(double adicional){
        if(turno == "noturno" || turno == "Noturno"){
            this.salario = this.salario+adicional;
        }
    }
}

public class Tecnico extends Assistente {

    public double bonusSalarial(){
        this.salario = this.salario+(this.salario*0.1);
        return this.salario;
    }

}
```

Existe algum erro na construção dos métodos e das heranças ou algum erro em geral levando em consideração o enunciado do exercício.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O enunciado não dá muitos detalhes, então tenho que considerar que um monte de coisa está certa, mesmo que eu não faria isso em código real, e o código faz coisas que o enunciado não pede. Também é verdade que o enunciado é esquisito.

Eu acho estranho uma classe ter um campo e só sua descendente ter um método `get` para pegar este campo, mas não posso falar que isto esteja errado de acordo com os fracos requisitos.

Fora isto não vejo problemas para um exercício simples (não vou comentar sobre dinheiro sendo manipulado com `double` porque isto não vem ao caso em um exercício).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Dinheiro eu devo manipular com float?

Comment: Não: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40048/101. E aconselho fortemente não ficar criando contas novas, vai atrapalhar seu aprendizado ter um monte de coisa espalhada.

Comment: Li a resposta no outro tópico, não sabia da classe Money, Vou estudar mais sobre. Só não entendi o que vc quis dizer com criar contas novas, seria ficar criando classes e classes em Java?

Comment: Não, já tem vários usuários que são seus aqui no site, o ideal é que só tivesse um. Seria até bom ver todos eles e pedir para um moderador para juntar em uma conta só.

Comment: Mas foi a primeira vez que criei conta aqui no site. Eu nunca havia criado conta aqui. Será que pode ter duplicado a conta ou dado algum erro? Tem como rastrear o e-mail para eu ver o nome dos outros usuários com o mesmo e-mail?

Comment: Você não é a Aline?

Comment: Não, meu nome real é Ewerton.

Comment: Me desculpe então, ela usa algumas contas com variações de Gon e faz perguntas do mesmo tema e do mesmo jeito que você, passou a impressão, esquece essa parte :)

Comment: Ah sim! Até assustei, pensei que alguém poderia estar usando meu e-mail. Estou pesquisando sobre a classe Java Money. Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda, estou iniciando os estudos e estou achando um pouco complicado agora no início.

Comment: Não disse que deve usá-la, apenas que o `double` não é adequada. Muita gente acha `Money` um exagero. Veja isto também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118407/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77747/101