# Como validar um campo do tipo double?

Tags: java, swing, aplicação-desktop

Boa tarde galera, não estou conseguindo validar o campo valor do tipo `double`

O campo que não consigo validar para o cadastro é o campo `valor`.

Segue o método classe para validar os dados para cadastrar:

```
 public boolean verificaDados(CardapioBeans cardapio, String valor){         

    if(cardapio.getDescricao().equals("")){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Descrição nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false;  
    }

    if(valor.equals("")){  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }  
    cardapioD.cadastrarCardapio(cardapio); 
    return true;  
}
```

Segue o método `cadastrarCardapio`:

```
public void cadastrarCardapio(CardapioBeans cardapio){
    try { 
        String SQLInsertion = "insert into cardapio(car_descricao, car_tipo, car_valor) "
            + "values(?,?,?);";

        PreparedStatement stm = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareStatement(SQLInsertion);
        stm.setString(1, cardapio.getDescricao()); 
        stm.setString(2, cardapio.getTipo());   
        stm.setDouble(3, cardapio.getValor());  

        stm.execute();  

        Conexao.getConnetion().commit(); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cadastrado com sucesso!","cadastro efetivado",1,new ImageIcon("Imagens/sucess.png"));

    } catch (SQLException ex) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel cadastrar","Erro de SQL", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
    }
}
```

Segue o Evento `B_CadastrarActionPerformed`:

```
private void B_CadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    capturaBeans();
    // se for true entra no if
    if(cardapioC.verificaDados(cardapioB, TF_Valor.getText())){ 
        limparTudo();
        habilitaTudo(false); // campos desabilitados para digitar 
    }    
}
```

Segue o método que captura os dados da tela:

```
final CardapioBeans capturaBeans(){
    cardapioB.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(TF_Codigo.getText())); 
    cardapioB.setDescricao(TA_Descricao.getText()); 
    cardapioB.setTipo(CB_Tipo.getSelectedItem().toString());
    cardapioB.setValor(Double.parseDouble(TF_Valor.getText()));

    return cardapioB; 
}
```

Segue o erro quando clico no botão cadastrar:

> ```
>    run:
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
>     at GUI.CardapioGUI.capturaBeans(CardapioGUI.java:387)
>     at GUI.CardapioGUI.B_CadastrarActionPerformed(CardapioGUI.java:294)
>     at GUI.CardapioGUI.access$400(CardapioGUI.java:10)
>     at GUI.CardapioGUI$6.actionPerformed(CardapioGUI.java:118)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 35 segundos)
> ```

Segue o codigo que valida se o usuario digitar um string 
Mas estou tentando fazer como validar o campo valor que é do tipo double,Imagina q o usuario clicou em cadastrar e esqueceu de preencher o campo valor do tipo double. Nao estou conseguindo implementar, obg

```
    private void TF_ValorFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                   
    try{
        double verifica = Double.parseDouble(TF_Valor.getText().replace(',','.'));
        TF_Valor.setText(formatoDecimal.format(verifica).replace(',', '.')); 
    } 
    catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor Deve Conter Apenas Números","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        TF_Valor.setText("");
        TF_Valor.requestFocus(); 
    }
}
```

Segue o erro NullPointerException: 
que acontece na classe CardapioGUI e CardapioController no metodo verificadados()

```
import Beans.CardapioBeans;
import Controller.CardapioController;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CardapioGUI extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    DefaultTableModel modelo;  
    CardapioController cardapioC;
    CardapioBeans cardapioB;
    DecimalFormat formatoDecimal;

    public CardapioGUI() { 
        initComponents();
        TF_Codigo.setEditable(false);  
        habilitaTudo(false);  
        modelo = (DefaultTableModel)Tabela.getModel(); 
        cardapioC = new CardapioController();
        cardapioB = new CardapioBeans(); 
        formatoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    }
    private void B_CadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        //capturaBeans();
        // se for true entra no if
        if(cardapioC.verificaDados(cardapioB, TF_Valor.getText())){ 
            capturaBeans();
            limparTudo();
            habilitaTudo(false); // campos desabilitados para digitar 
        }    
    }
```

Cardapio controller :

```
public boolean verificaDados(CardapioBeans cardapio, String valor){         

    if(cardapio.getDescricao().equals("")){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Descrição nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false;  
    }
    if(valor.equals("")){  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
    return false; 
}
try {
    Double.parseDouble(valor);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não é um número","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
    return false;
}
cardapioD.cadastrarCardapio(cardapio); 
return true;  
}
```

Comment: O campo `carValor` aceita nulo no banco de dados? O método é `cardapioB.setValor(Double)` ou `cardapioB.setValor(double)`? Ou seja, ele usa `double` com letra minúscula ou `Double` com letra maiúscula?

Comment: Ah, você deveria usar o *try-with-resources* no seu `PreparedStatement`. Do jeito que está, se ocorrer um `SQLException`, ele não será fechado adequadamente. Veja mais [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Comment: Se é valor monetário, pode começar não usando `double` já que isto é um erro. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77746/101

Comment: Boa parte dessa validação poderia ter eliminada usando [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html). A experiência final do usuário também fica muito melhor já que o feedback é imediato (ele não precisa submeter o formulário). Você pode usar o seu `DecimalFormat`  (com `setParseBigDecimal(true)` vide conselho do bigown) e um valor padrão (e.g., `0.00`) para inicializar o `JFormattedTextField`. Com isso o valor nunca estará vazio, sempre será válido e você pode recuperar o tipo desejado (`BigDecimal`, `Double`, etc) com `getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente trocar isso:

```
    if(valor.equals("")){  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }
```

Por isso:

```
    if (valor.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo Valor não pode ser vazio.", "Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }

    try {
        Double.parseDouble(valor);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo Valor deve ser preenchido com um número.", "Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }
```

Ou então, seguindo a sugestão do Maniero, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
    BigDecimal valorNumerico;
    try {
        valorNumerico = new BigDecimal(valor);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo Valor deve ser preenchido com um número.", "Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }
```

No seu método `capturaBeans()` você faz algo parecido com isso, exibindo a mensagem de erro e/ou fazendo a validação correspondente.

Comment: Não deu certo, aparece o mesmo erro: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String . Como tratar esse erro no 'capturaBeans()' /

Answer (score 0):

Não adianta apenas verificar se o valor é vazio; o correto é verificar se a `String` enviada é realmente um número. Na sua função `verificaDados()`:

Altere:

```
if(valor.equals("")) {  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
    return false; 
}
```

Por:

```
try {
    Double.parseDouble(valor);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
}
```

Comment: O metodo verificar se é String ou não eu ja tenho. Mas quando o valor é vazio ele mostra o erro q que esta na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nessa parte:

```
private void B_CadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    capturaBeans();
    // se for true entra no if
    if(cardapioC.verificaDados(cardapioB, TF_Valor.getText())){ 
        limparTudo();
        habilitaTudo(false); // campos desabilitados para digitar 
    }    
}
```

Você está mandando ele capturar os valores (no `capturaBeans()`) e depois verifica se eles são válidos (com o `cardapioC.verificaDados(cardapioB, TF_Valor.getText())`).

Altere o seu método para ele só capturar os valores depois de validá-los:

```
private void B_CadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // se for true entra no if
    if(cardapioC.verificaDados(cardapioB, TF_Valor.getText())){ 
        capturaBeans();
        limparTudo();
        habilitaTudo(false); // campos desabilitados para digitar 
    }    
}
```

Além disso, você deve validar se sua `String` realmente é um `double` no seu método `verificaDados(CardapioBeans cardapio, String valor)` :

```
public boolean verificaDados(CardapioBeans cardapio, String valor){         

    if(cardapio.getDescricao().equals("")){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Descrição nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false;  
    }

    if(valor.equals("")){  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false; 
    }
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(valor);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Valor não é um número","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        return false;
    }
    cardapioD.cadastrarCardapio(cardapio); 
    return true;
```

}

Comment: Não funciona, dá um java.lang.NullPointerException na linha 20

Comment: @Jose.Lemo pode mostrar a stack trace da `NullPointerException` e a classe completa de onde ela é lançada?

Comment: Sim. Na classe CardapioGUI (Linha 10) na classe CardapioController no método verificadados linha 20 (no primeiro if).Vou editar para colocar essas classes