# Qual a melhor forma de armazenar valores monetários no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, valor-monetário

Li [esse *post* sobre a falta de precisão do `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77592/como-converter-string-para-double-sem-erro-de-arredondamento), e praticamente todos os links dos links do *post*.

Então percebi que está era uma vulnerabilidade de meu software em produção (já que tenho `rounds` para todo canto antes de fazer qualquer tipo de calculo relacionado a valores monetários). Então antes de ter maiores problemas com o bolso dos clientes. Resolvi refatorar meu sistema utilizando `BigDecimal` para todos os atributos relacionados a valores monetários.

Ao chegar na camada de acesso a base de dados me deparei com um problema/dúvida de como armazenar estes valores de forma confiável e precisa no Banco de Dados SQLite?

Pesquisando encontrei algumas possibilidades:

1. Salvar em uma coluna `INTEGER`, em forma de centavos, por exemplo: `BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal("1.67")`, na base ficaria: `long valueInCents = valor.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).longValue()`, o que resultaria em 167 na coluna do banco de dados, necessitando do processo reverso ao obter o valor do banco de dados novamente. (Essa é que achei mais eficaz, pratica e interessante até o momento);
2. Salvar em duas colunas `INTEGER` uma para a parte inteira do valor e outra para a parte decimal. (Essa é mais abrangente pois daria liberdade para utilizar quantas casas decimais forem necessárias até o limite do `INTEGER` do SQLite que **acho** que é 18, mas para o caso de valores monetário talvez seja um esforço desnecessário, se você trabalhar apenas com as 2 casas de centavos);
3. Salvar em uma coluna do tipo `TEXT` e sempre converte de `BigDecimal` para `String` e de `String` para `BigDecimal`. (Essa seria a solução mais pratica, já que o `BigDecimal` tem um construtor para o valor em `String`, mas apesar disso é a solução que menos me agrada já que não teria o valor numérico na base de dados, então qualquer calculo com essa coluna deveria ser feito via aplicação).

#### Dúvidas

- A coluna do tipo `REAL`, ou qualquer outra variante decimal, teria precisão para armazenar esse valor `BigDecimal` mantendo a precisão sem maiores problemas?
- Qual das 3 possibilidades mencionadas anteriormente (ou alguma solução extra) seria mais adequada e eficiente para armazenar valores monetários (com apenas 2 casas de centavos. Ex: `1.67`)?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O tipo `real` do SQLite é o `double`, não use.

Escolher uma para você cairia na opinião. Depende do que precisa, de como fica mais confortável para trabalhar. Vou indicar os problemas e já lhe informando que não há forma melhor de resolver isto a não ser mudando o SQLite.

- A primeira tem a dificuldade de ter que tratar no código (Java ou SQL) o acerto das casas decimais. Não é o fim do mundo mas tem quem não goste. Dá até para criar uma classe que abstraia isto para você e aí não precisa se preocupar para todo lado na aplicação. Mas nas *queries* SQL tem que lembrar sempre.
- A segunda tem essencialmente o mesmo problema e é mais complicado fazer certo (as fórmulas terão que ser mais complexas, embora dê para criar classes no Java e funções para o SQL para cuidar disto, abstraindo o problema). A única vantagem que vejo é permitir valores bem grandes, mas não sei se eles são necessários. [Talvez seja no Zimbábue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_Zimbabwe). Ainda fico com a primeira, mas seu caso pode exigir esta forma, mas duvido.
- A terceira também tem esse problema de ter que tratar. Precisa converter para fazer cálculos em todo uso. E tem que tomar cuidado para não converter para numérico binário (tipo `real`) quando for usar, mesmo que sem querer, aí deu na mesma que usar o `real` ou `double`. Dá para fazer os cálculos com ela mas dá trabalho. Sem uma forma melhor de abstração eu não iria nela, mas é gosto.

[Outros *sites* da rede](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15729/41) tem [respostas para isto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261220/221800) e é quase unânime que a primeira é melhor, também acho.

Fora isto, mude o SQLite para suportar um novo tipo de dado :)

Tudo é uma questão de abstração. Se você puder fazer ficar transparente tudo muda. No Java é um pouco mais fácil fazer isto do que no SQLite.

Alguns vão achar que criando uma classe que abstraia isto vai resolver fácil. Não é bem assim. Quando você multiplica uma número com 2 casas e outro com 4 casas, o resultado deve ter 2, 4, 6 ou outro número de casas? Haverá uma perda no arredondamento e algum centavo ou fração de centavo ficará possivelmente perdido. O que fazer com ele? Se você dividir um valor em prestações, vai sobrar centavos por causa do arredondamento, onde ele deve ser colocado? Nas primeiras prestações? Nas últimas? Intercalado? Só na primeira ou só na última? Cada situação vai exigir uma solução. E os cálculos intermediários para se chegar em um resultado?

Pode ser interessante ter um código canônico que trate disto e que de alguma forma abstraia isto, mas isto terá que ser feito através de políticas, com decoradores, com estratégias, ou outras formas, não dá para criar uma classe `Money` ou a já existente `Currency` por exemplo, e ela não saberá lidar com tudo.

A [Joda Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money) ajuda nisso mas não resolve tudo. Java adotou a Joda em suas APIs mais novas.

Lembrando que isto é importante com dinheiro mas vale também para outros valores que dependam de exatidão. Quantidades que podem ser fracionadas de qualquer tipo usam isto. Seríamos felizes se não houvesse centavos ou as quantidades pudessem ser normalizadas para a capacidade mínima para não ter casas decimais. Ainda assim o problema descrito nos parágrafos anteriores teria que ser tratado.

Esta resposta vale para quem está usando o SQLite com outras linguagens ou sistemas operacionais ou dispositivos.

Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa do Zimbábue eu não sabia, impressionante o quadro. A inflação nos últimos ano é absolutamente surreal!

Comment: Pois é @bigown, também estou mais para a primeira opção, só tenho/tinha duvida se era o melhor solução para valores monetários ou se havia outras opções melhores. E em relação a abstração independente da abordagem escolhida criaria uma `class` (talvez chamada _Currency_) que herde de `BigDecimal` e já implemente as conversões, facilitando o uso e centralizando o algoritmo.

Comment: @Fernando é, ajuda, mas não resolve todas as situações. Não vou entrar em detalhes aqui, mas cada operação pode ter uma regra própria de arredondamento. Dá para resolver tudo dentro da classe mas é trabalhoso e complicado. Conhece a [Joda Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money)? Ajuda mas não resolve tudo. De qualquer forma isto resolve no lado do Java mas ainda não resolve quando usar SQL.

Comment: E se minha aplicação fosse somente para o Zimbábue, colocaria os valores monetários em um `INTEGER`, pois os centavos não devem valer nada lá. Hehe! Pois eles tem [notas de 100.000.000.000.000 (100 trilhões)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_Zimbabwe#/media/File:Zimbabwe_$100_trillion_2009_Obverse.jpg).

Comment: Não sei se cabe altos valores. Mas aí o problema é outro. E parece que vai resolver mês que vem. Desistiram. Vão adotar o dólar americano.

Comment: Atualmente trabalho num aplicativo que processa pagamentos, um mPOS, e utilizamos o protocolo ISO-8583 pra isso. Todo valor monetário que trafegamos e armazenamos fica no formato inteiro sendo os dois últimos dígitos as duas casas decimais. É meio que um padrão por aqui. Não sei se seria interessante pra você trabalhar dessa forma.