# Números diferentes se tornam iguais após conversão com doubleval

Tags: php, conversão-de-tipo, float, valor-monetário

Tenho 2 valores 4850.00 e 4850.01

Quando defino 2 variáveis manualmente com esses valores e comparo usando `if`, me retorna diferente (OK).

Mas em um sistema ERP que desenvolvo recebo 2 valores via AJAX. Ambos, os mesmos valores acima e mesmo convertendo para `doubleval($var1)` `doubleval($var2)` quando uso a comparação me retorna igual.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código e verificar o tamanho das strings também? nesse [exemplo](https://ideone.com/bm6TxO) com um espaço entre o separador de decimal ele apenas considerou o valor númerico e descartou o resto.

Comment: Eu não consigo reproduzir o problema. Veja: http://ideone.com/GQ2SkS

Comment: Desculpem mas eu estava errado. Na comparação usei uma variável com nome muito parecido e por isso ocorria o erro. Desculpem minha falta de atenção. (Só podia ser isso msm rsrs).

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

E vamos nós de novo. Vou responder porque ainda não tem uma resposta para PHP, e alguém vai responder antes da pergunta ser fechada como duplicata.

Não pode usar tipo `double` ou equivalente quando necessita precisão numérica. Este tipo de dado é feito para processar rápido e não para ser exato.

O ideal nestes casos é usar inteiros e apresentar como deseja, com a quantidade de casas que deseja. Ou seja trate tudo como a menor unidade possível, por exemplo, centavos, assim não precisa cuidar das casas decimais. Ainda assim terá que saber como lidar com os arredondamentos necessários.

Duvido que seja o caso, mas se não precisar de cálculos e só precisar comparar, trate tudo como *string*. Isto raramente se aplica, mas é uma opção.

Ou ainda criar ou usar uma classe para um tipo decimal ou monetário. Tem [bibliotecas](http://money.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Introduction.html) prontas mas não gosto delas, nem mesmo a [padrão](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Existem diversas perguntas sobre o assunto aqui:

- [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101)
- [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77592/101)
- [Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101)
- [C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101)
- [MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101)
- [SQL Server/C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/101)
- [SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78306/101)

Veja também [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Lendo tudo, seguindo os *link* dá para aprender bem porque isto acontece e como evitar em qualquer situação em qualquer linguagem ou software.

O problema é este, usar o tipo de dado errado fará sempre ter problemas. Qualquer tentativa de contornar com alguma gambiarra apenas criará a ilusão de solução.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).