# Formatando decimal

Tags: objective-c, formatação, valor-monetário

Estou com um problema na formatação de casas decimais em meu código em Objective-c, gostaria de aproveitar apenas 2 casas decimais de minha variável que é `float`.

Ex: Valor da variavel `discount = 4.00043621`

e preciso que fique armazenado apenas `4.00`

Consigui formatar apenas com o `StringWithFormat`, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
NSString* decimalFormatado = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.02f", discount];
```

desta maneira o valor da variável `decimalFormatado` ficou da forma como eu queria "4.00" porém, em `String`. e preciso que continue em `float`, pois precisarei usá-lo como `float` em uma estrutura condicional mais a frente.

Alguma sugestão para a melhor forma de como fazer isto?

Estou procurando uma forma de aproveitar apenas as 2 casas apos a vírgula com uma formatação direta, converter de `string` para `decimal` com as duas casas acredito não ser uma boa prática.

Comment: Você fala em decimal mas está usando um `float`. Aparentemente está usando em coisas que envolvem dinheiro. Você tem certeza que quer fazer isto? Você não acha estranho que o valor seja `4.00043621`? Se fizer uma conta com isto, sabe que vai dar resultados inesperados e que costumam ser considerados errados?

Comment: acabei de perceber amigo, vou usar arredondamento ao inves de truncate, muito obrigado! responda ai que ja lhe positivo!

Comment: Mas se vc ainda usará o número para cálculos basta mantê-lo na variável original... Para o número formatado declare normalmente como NSString numa outra variável como já está sendo feito..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formatação deve ser feita como `string` mesmo. Números formatados são textos a serem apresentados, portanto este é o tipo correto.

O que você quer não é formatação, você quer pegar o valor exato, e isto não é possível com o tipo `float`.

Normalmente eu nem responderia e fecharia como duplicata porque existe inúmeras perguntas sobre o assunto aqui mas ainda não existia sobre Objective-C. [O "problema" está no processador e afeta todas linguagens igualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

A solução é simples, se precisa de uma informação decimal, use um tipo que trate de forma decimal o número que precisa tratar. `float` não é decimal, é binário.

Arredondamento não resolve o problema, só o disfarça.

[Leia mais em outras perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78742/101). Mas leia mesmo, tudo, siga todos os *links*. Aprenda porque isto é importante para evitar prejuízos para seus usuários.

Nesta linguagem o tipo é o [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html). Algumas pessoas preferem trabalhar com inteiros. Arredondamentos ainda serão necessários nos dois casos, mas pelo menos serão feitos da forma correta. Com um tipo de ponto flutuante binário sempre terá erros, mesmo que em alguns casos não parece ter.

Comment: entendi, obrigado!