# Como arredondar valores do tipo Double?

Tags: ios, swift, valor-monetário

Fiz uma função para retornar o arredondamento de valores do tipo `Double`,
a função esta funcionando, porem não sei se é a maneira ideal para se ter esse resultado, penso que deve existir uma maneira sem ter que utilizar a classe `String`.

```
var numero: Double = 6.73865

func arredonda(valor: Double, casasdecimais: Int)-> Double{
    let formato = String(casasdecimais)+"f"
    return Double(String(format: "%."+formato, valor))!
}

arredonda(numero, casasdecimais:  3)
```

// retorna  6.739

```
arredonda(numero, casasdecimais:  2)
```

//  retorna 6.74

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem como ter controle sobre as casas decimais em um número do tipo `double`, isto é característica dele. Se precisa disto, precisa usar outro tipo de dado. No caso seria o [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html). Também será útil a classe [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/)

Leia mais sobre isto na [resposta sobre o Objective C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81827/101). E continue seguindo todos os *links* para entender porque isto ocorre.

Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, não tive tempo de todas as suas respostas do SOP mas dei uma lida no NSNumberFormatter, a minha intenção é mesmo aprender mais sobre a linguagem e não ficar programando por gambiarras.

Answer (score 1):

Em Swift podemos criar [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) (que é parecido com as [Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) do Objective-C), então podemos adicionar uma nova funcionalidade para a classe `Double`:

```
extension Double {
    /// Arredonda um Double conforme quantidade de casas decimais
    func arredonda(casas: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(casas))
        return round(self * divisor) / divisor
    }
}


let a = Double(0.123456789).arredonda(4)  //0.1235
let b = Double(0.123456789).arredonda(5)  //0.12346
let c = Double(6.73865).arredonda(3)  //6.739
let d = Double(6.73865).arredonda(2)  //6.74
```

Comment: não conhecia o extensions @iTsangar, fiz uma mescla da sua resposta com a do _bigown_ e estou editando na sua resposta, fique a vontade para fazer as alterações necessárias. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @FábioReibnitz recomendo você criar uma nova resposta com as edições que você fez na minha resposta, assim fica mais organizado.

Comment: ok @iTsangar , acho que fica mais apropriado utilizar o NSNumberFormatter, permite posteriormente fazer futuras outras modificações caso  haja necessidade. Mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

**Após as respostas do @Maniero e @iTSanguar  fiz uma função que utiliza parte dos conceitos apresentados por eles e também me por esta que encontrei  no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571782/singleton-and-nsnumberformatter-in-swift)**

```
extension Double {
        /// Arredonda um Double conforme quantidade de casas decimais
        func arredonda(casasDecimais: Int) -> Double {
            var formatacao:String {
                let formatacao = NSNumberFormatter()
                formatacao.minimumFractionDigits = casasDecimais
                return formatacao.stringFromNumber(self)!

        }
        return Double(formatacao)!

    }
}
var numero: Double  = 6.73865
numero.arredonda(3) // 6.739
numero.arredonda(2) // 6.74
```

Comment: Mas você disse que não queria fazer gambiarras :)

Comment: @bigown hahaha, e eu achava que tava indo bem.. o que me aconselharia? tirar o extension? tirar a função do extension?

Comment: Torar o `Double`. Se você continuar usando um tipo que não pode garantir o a exatidão dos valores, vai ter problemas. Por isso que eu falei pra ler tudo. O tipo de ponto flutuante não pode representar todos os valores decimais possíveis, então estes artifícios de arredondamento não funcionam. É que eu não tenho como executar Swift, senão eu te mostraria que alguns números vão dar certo, outro não. Agora, se você não liga para exatidão, aí pode usar. Alguns tipos de uso, a exatidão não é importante. Mas não espere que mantenha o número de casas decimais.

Comment: @bigwon tudo começou quando estava passando funções do excel pra swift e os valores foram diferentes.. coisas de 0.0001 então comecei a tentar forçar um arredondamento.. porem mais pra frente vi que o erro era em outro lugar.. e não precisa mais do arredondamento.. mas como já tinha feito a gambiarra, quis colocar em discussão, realmente não tive tempo de ler tudo, mas o que me chamou a atenção, foi que destas formas apresentada ele faz o arredondamento.. que em muitos casos é importante.. por exemplo.. aluno ficou com media 6,78 ele arredonda pra 7

Comment: Você está descrevendo o problema do `double`. Eu te falei o que acontece de fato, se você quer confiar na coincidência, fica a seu critério. Todos os bons programadores sabem como fazer do jeito certo e garantido.

Comment: Vou continuar pesquisando nos links que me sugeristes e ver se encontro a melhor solução, confesso que me falta ler o NSDecimalNumber e mais outros links.. porque a tripa é grande hehe. Mais um vez obrigado!