# Como calcular porcentagem?

Tags: php, matemática, porcentagem

Tenho uma variável que recebe dinamicamente do banco de dados, um número flutuante que é a porcentagem a ser retirada de um determinado valor. Como faço para tirar esta porcentagem de um valor?

Por exemplo:

```
$total = 4000;
$pctm = 30.00;
$valor_descontado = $total-$pctm.'%';
```

Mas assim, não funciona.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Isto é matemática básica. Para se calcular porcentagem se divide por 100 e multiplica pela porcentagem que se deseja.

```
$total = 4000;
$pctm = 30.00;
$valor_descontado = $total - ($total / 100 * $pctm); //os parenteses são desnecessários
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w5vzQY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lpcajlid-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Percent.php).

É claro que estamos falando de valores monetários e [aí você tem outro problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78735/101).

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado não só a você, mas a todos.

Comment: @Maniero, como eu faço para obter a porcentagem do resultado da subtração de 2500000 por 1950000. Eu tentei com a proposta ai, mas não funciona, ele não retorna o valor da porcentagem. Será que é porque o número é grande? Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: @Maniero eu quero saber qual é a porcentagem do número que eu subtrair. Por exemplo. Meu produto custa 100 reais, eu vou dá um desconto de 25 reais, ou seja diminuir... é uma conta simples já sabemos de cabeça que o percentual de 100 reais menos 25 é de 25%. Mas e para números maiores? Por exemplo, qual é a porcentagem de 5 milhões - menos 1 milhão setecentos e cinquenta mil e 80 reais? Eu estou em busca "do %%%" do resultado do número que eu acabei de subtrair...

Answer (score 8):

Basta efetuar um cálculo simples.

```
$valor_descontado = $total - $total * $pctm / 100.0;
```

Considerando que:

> 30% = 30/100

Answer (score 8):

Basta utilizar regrinha de 3:

```
function porcentagem_nx ( $parcial, $total ) {
    return ( $parcial * 100 ) / $total;
}
```

Com esta função irá facilitar o cálculo de porcentagem, para utilizar basta:

```
 porcentagem_nx(20, 100); // 20
```

[Ver funcionando no Codepag](http://codepad.org/tKxbgtUy)

Comment: Bem lembrado +1, a regra de 3.

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$total = 4000
$pctm = 30.00

$valor_com_desconto = $total - ($total * $pctm * 0.01)
```

Dividir por 100 e multiplicar por 0.01 dá o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu geralmente faço assim para capturar o resultado de um desconto:

```
$total = 4000;
$pctm = 30.00;
$valor_com_desconto = $total - (($total * $pctm) / 100);
echo $valor_com_desconto;
```

**Obs:** a matemática sempre executa a multiplicação depois a divisão. Neste exemplo a lógica está separada.

Comment: Na verdade, multiplicação e divisão possuem a mesma "importância" na ordem de execução, o famoso P/E/MD/AS http://pt.wikihow.com/Calcular-uma-Express%C3%A3o-Usando-PEMDAS

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma é pelo fator de multiplicação, exemplo:

Se um produto aumentou 30% então seu fator de multiplicação é de 1 + taxa de acréscimo, sendo essa taxa de 0,3. Portanto, seu fator de multiplicação é de 1,3.

Se um produto teve um desconto de 30% então seu fator de multiplicação é de 1 - taxa de decréscimo, sendo essa taxa de 0,3. Portanto, seu fator de multiplicação é de 0,7.

```
$total = 4000;
$pctm = -30.00;//desconto de 30%
echo "Com desconto: " . $total * (1+($pctm/100));
echo PHP_EOL;
$pctm = 30.00;//acréscimo de 30%
echo "Com acréscimo: " . $total * (1+($pctm/100));
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/ZzaFn4)