# Quando usar cada tipo de dado do mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, tipagem

Segundo a [`documentação`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> **i** - corresponding variable has type integer
>   **d** - corresponding variable has type double 
>   **s** - corresponding variable has type string 
>   **b** - corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in
>   packets

Então queria saber quando exatamente usar cada cada um destes tipos, quais caracteres cada um destes tipos aceita.

A duvida surgiu porque no banco MySQL uso por exemplo `VARCHAR` pra salvar valores de moeda, e sempre associei o `VARCHAR` com `string`, então tava passando os valores de moeda como `s`, mas vi que o certo é com `d`, porque no banco estava salvando sem `.`e sem `,`. O `s` aceita apenas letras? Double aceita apenas números e `.` e `,`? Pra que serve o `b`? Enfim, uma explicação geral e atualizada seria legal. Valeu.

Comment: Colunas com números fracionados o separador de milhar é ponto geralmente. `b` é para dados binários, por exemplo guardar um upload de uma imagem.

Comment: Valores de moeda seria dinheiro? Talvez seja legal usar o DECIMAL.

Comment: Sobre o problema de usar double/float/real tem algumas perguntas, vale apena dar uma olhada em: [Números diferentes se tornam iguais após conversão com doubleval](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78742/91) e [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como dito pelo @rray o `b` é usado pra dados binários, por exemplo fotos, arquivos zipados, etc.

Os tipos `VARCHAR` e `TEXT` são campos que usam `string` ou seja aceitam de A á Z de 0 á 9, então o uso deve ser o `s`, não use pra fazer cálculos.

Então os caracteres suportados variam conforme a coleção usada. Por exemplo:

- `utf8_general_ci` suporta caracteres unicode no entanto é mais simples.
- `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` suporta a maioria (se não todos) caracteres unicode.
- `latin1_general_ci` não usa unicode, mas suporta acentos.

Ou seja, o `s` você pode passar um string, mas quando o processo chegar na query os caracteres *podem* ser perder se não forem compatíveis com a `collection` usada.

### Trabalhando com valores Monetários

Se vai usar valores monetários, talvez o melhor seja usar `DECIMAL` (note que não vai usar **virgula**).

Veja esta respostas (apesar de falar sobre sql-server): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5760/3635

### O tipo decimal

O tipo decimal não tem os mesmos problemas de precisão dos tipos `float` e `double`. Ele é um tipo de ponto fixo, e não flutuante. Em outras palavras, se você define um campo em um banco de dados como MySQL do tipo `DECIMAL(10,2)`, quer dizer que será um número (em base 10) com 10 dígitos, sendo que 2 deles serão após a vírgula. Sempre. Alguns bancos de dados inclusive armazenam internamente dados desse tipo como strings.

Essa estratégia de armazenamento elimina o problema dos arredondamentos no armazenamento dos dados, mas por outro lado isso diminui a flexibilidade do tipo. Enquanto pode não ser uma boa escolha para dados em que o número de casas decimais não pode ser definido, é uma boa opção por exemplo para valores financeiros (já que esses sempre têm 2 casas decimais).

Deve se levar em conta também que em alguns casos, valores do tipo decimal serão convertidos em números de ponto flutuante de forma implícita quando forem usados em cálculos. Nesse caso se o resultado esperado também do tipo decimal, ele será arredondado e convertido de float para decimal. Ou seja, a precisão é melhor, mas não é ilimitada.

<sub>Fonte: http://douglascunha.com/blog/2010/08/tipos-sql-float-double-decimal/#sthash.VGlFZBL7.dpuf</sub>

Comment: Vou melhorar a resposta, notei agora que tem algumas subperguntas.

Comment: Valeu, acho que vc foi no cerne do meu problema, que era estar usando o tipo errado no banco... acho que pra ficar perfeito vc podia falar algo sobre cada tipo de dado. Sobre o `b`já tá bem claro, mas sobre o `s` por exemplo, ele aceita apenas as letras do alfabeto? Quando eu for guardar um trecho em HTML por exemplo, qual o tipo certo?  Valeu por enquanto! +1

Comment: @gustavox `s` é para string e string aceita qualquer tipo de caracteres dentro do tipo de codificação selecionada, por exemplo `latin1_general_ci`, todos caracteres ASCII seriam aceitos ou `utf8_general_ci` aceita varios caracteres unicode.

Comment: Então é o tipo certo pra guardar trechos HTML né... valeu cara, vc e alguns outros users daqui tem me ajudado muito! Abraços.

Comment: @gustavox Sim pode guardar html pois os caracteres são ASCII e as coleções de caracteres do mysql suportam tais caracteres, mesmo a mais basica - Nota: na verdade eu prefiro guardar exatamente o que o usuário escrever, mesmo que ele injete html aonde não podia e só uso `htmlspecialchars` na leitura após usar o `SELECT ...`. Mas isto é uma opinião minha :) - Agora pra valor monetário realmente o melhor é decimal - Abraço

Comment: Saquei, valeu! Abraços!

Comment: Então cara, vim aqui consultar de novo este tópico e vi que não tem nada sobre o `d`, e to com uma pequena dúvida, porque preciso aplicar a vários campos e queria ter certeza mesmo antes de fazer, porque são muitos campos... dinheiro e percentual devo usar o `d` mesmo né? DECIMAL no MySQL e o `d`no `bind_param` né? Quais os caracteres que o `d`aceita? Concedi uma pequena recompensa por esta resposta, e pelos esclarecimentos, e por tudo que vc tem me ajudado... valeu!

Comment: @gustavox Eu nem lembrava kk - Obrigado!! :) Vou tentar adicionar algumas "dicas" na resposta a noite pra ti.

Comment: Tranquilo cara, só tenho a agradecer! Valeu!

Comment: Valeu cara, é uma honra saber que vc curtiu a resposta do github! (to postando aqui pra vc não esquecer das dicas kkkkk) Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @gustavox Você acredita que algum safado roubou os fios de telefone da rua de cima da minha casa e afetou o bairro todo, to sem net, to usando o 3g, amanhã se a internet estiver legal eu edito e adicione as dicas lá. Até mais!

Comment: Nossa, obrigar alguém a usar o 3G, isso sim devia ser crime hediondo! :)