# Arredondamento de 5 em 5 centavos

Tags: php, mysql, arredondamento

Em um sistema PHP que estou desenvolvendo, preciso atualizar uma coluna da tabela de preço. O campo preço está no formato `float` e o administrador informa o percentual de aumento.

Exemplo: Informa que terá 10% de aumento.

```
$valor_antigo = 4,25;

$novo_valor = round(($valor_antigo + ($valor_antigo / $percentual)),2);
```

Assim, o valor após o aumento será de 4,68. Definindo para deixar apenas duas casas após a vírgula.

O que preciso agora é arredondar esse valores de cinco em cinco centavos. Se eu utilizar `ceil` ou `floor, terei esse arredondamento apenas de 1 em 1.

Por exemplo, o valor de 4,68 acima, precisa ser salvo como 4,70.
`
Se o valor fosse 5,22; ficaria 5,20. 7,46, ficaria 7,45.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Isso é importante corrigir logo: "O campo preço está no formato float". O MySQL tem um campo muito melhor pra isso, que é o `int`. Se faz questão de armazenar o separador decimal junto do número, tem o tipo `decimal` também (mas se o número de casas for fixo, eu ainda prefiro o `int`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tem que normalizar no ponto que deseja. Se quer a cada 5 centavos divide-se o valor por 0,05 arredondando ele e aí multiplica-se novamente por 0,05 (5 centavos), assim volta-se ao valor original sem a parte fracionada indesejada.

```
round($value / 0.05, 0) * 0.05
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pcn8rI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fblgftis-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/RoundFiveCents.php).

Usar [`float` para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78735/101) é pedir para ter problemas.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.