# Não consigo inserir valores definidos pelo usuário no SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com um problema onde não consigo adicionar nada na tabela e sempre aparece o erro:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably
>   unsupported type.

O código que estou tentando adicionar valores e este:

```
  p_name=input("Digite o nome do produto: "),
  p_desc=input("Digite a descrição: "),
  p_costp=input("Digite o preço de custo: "),
  p_sellp=input("Digite o preço de venda: ")
  c.execute("INSERT INTO products (name,description,costp,sellp) VALUES
(?,?,?,?)",(p_name,p_desc,p_costp,p_sellp))
```

E a minha Tabela:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    costp REAL, 
    sellp REAL)")
```

Inserir com valores pré-definidos dá certo, mas valores recebidos do usuário eu não consigo e sempre aparece este erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, [usar `REAL` para guardar valores monetários é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78306/101).

Se quiser insistir, precisa converter o dado recebido pelo `input()` em um tipo com ponto flutuante para corresponder com o tipo `REAL`, assim:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO products (name, description, costp, sellp)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (p_name, p_desc, float(p_costp), float(p_sellp)))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/InsertDatabase.py).

Esta é uma forma simplista, mas funciona se o valor for digitado corretamente. Idealmente a conversão seria feita antes e trataria exceção se ela não der certo. Mas como parece ser só um teste, isso não é tão importante.

Answer (score 0):

uma forma de estar passando os valores para seu sql bem útil que sempre funciona, é usando a passagem de parâmetros por tuplas.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO products (name,description,costp,sellp) VALUES ('%s','%s',%f,%f)" %(p_name,p_desc,p_costp,p_sellp))
```

de preferencia, não se esqueça das aspas simples para os valores do tipo **TEXT**