# Valores decimais sendo arredondados no SQLIte

Tags: c#, sqlite3

Após migrar meu banco de dados de Access para o SQLite 3 numa aplicação Windows Forms, venho tendo dificuldades com os valores do tipo Decimal. Se executo um select simples:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE id = 1;
```

Os valores decimais da coluna preco_item apresentam corretamente, com 2 casas decimais. Exemplo: 2,53 = 2,53. Mas quando faço uma consulta um pouco mais complexa, com tabelas relacionadas como a seguir:

```
SELECT Produto.nome AS Produto, 
                Item.quantidade AS Quantidade, 
                Item.preco_item AS Preço,     
                Item.preco_item * Item.quantidade as Subtotal,               
                Item.id  
            FROM Item  
            INNER JOIN Orcamento ON Item.id_orcam = Orcamento.id   
            INNER JOIN Produto ON Item.id_produto = Produto.id   
            WHERE(Orcamento.id = 1 );
```

Os resultados obtidos na linha Preço se apresentam no `DataTable` assim: `2,53` = `2,00`, assim também acontece com o resultado da multiplicação `preco_item * quantidade`.

Observação: os itens monetários estão configurados como Decimal(7,2) no SQLite. Já tentei diversos outros formatos. Na consulta pelo SQLite Studio, os resultados de preço se apresentam normalmente, com exceção da multiplicação que eu ainda não achei uma forma de calcular corretamente. Sempre me retorna um valor inteiro.

P.S.: Os valores são inseridos em um DataGridView por meio de DataTable.

Atualização para demonstrar o esquema do BD:

```
private static string createQuery()
{
        string createScript = "CREATE TABLE Cliente (" +
            " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            " nome       TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
            " endereco   TEXT," +
            " local      TEXT," +
            " telefone_1 TEXT," +
            " telefone_2 TEXT ); ";
        createScript += "CREATE TABLE Produto (" +
             " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
             " nome  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
             " preco DECIMAL ); ";
        createScript += "CREATE TABLE Tipo (" + 
            " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"  + 
            " nome      TEXT," + 
            " descricao TEXT ); ";
        createScript += "CREATE TABLE Orcamento (" +
            " id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " id_cliente INTEGER REFERENCES Cliente (id)," +
            " data DATETIME," +
            " id_tipo INTEGER REFERENCES Tipo(id)," +
            " desconto DECIMAL," +
            " status TEXT DEFAULT Pendente ); ";
        createScript += "CREATE TABLE Item (" +
            " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            " id_orcam INTEGER REFERENCES Orcamento (id)," + 
            " id_produto INTEGER REFERENCES Produto(id)," +
            " preco_item DECIMAL," + 
            " quantidade INTEGER NOT NULL ); ";

        return createScript;
}
```

Eis o código que preenche o DataGridView:

```
string query = Queries.GetItemsByOrcId(orcId);
sql.CustomSelect(query);
dgvpProd.DataSource = sql.Datatable;
```

Comment: Não existe "Decimal(7,2)" no SQLite. Ou é INTEGER, ou é REAL. E REAL você não deve usar em hipótese alguma pra preço. O caminho menos doloroso geralmente é criar um INTEGER de nome preco_item100, por exemplo, e guardar 2,35 como 235. Ou preco_item1000 se precisar de 3 casas, como o pessoal de posto de gasolina faz. (esse número no nome é uma técnica pra facilitar a vida e você sempre saber onde por a vírgula e/ou quanto é o divisor, é só uma dica). No pior dos casos tem que armazenar como caractere, mas aí entendo que causa outros problemas.

Comment: Nota: pra falar a verdade, mesmo quando o banco suporta, ainda acho o preco100 melhor que o decimal, a não ser que vc precise de alguma abstração que o tipo oferece no lado da linguagem cliente.

Comment: Entendi. Vou experimentar remover as vírgulas no insert e achar um modo de tratar os valores como formato de moeda no c#. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá amigo, infelizmente já estou refatorando tudo de acordo com a dica do Bacco. Mas em resumo eu estava gerando um datatable com o resultado do select e usando o método Source do Datagridview para populá-lo. O type da coluna preco ficava em decimal de acordo com o modelo da coluna do BD, mas o resultado sempre arredondava quando era exibido no DGV. Agora coloquei as colunas do BD como int, dividindo por 100 e parseando o resultado decimal para string e usando as colunas com type string.

Comment: Ali tem o segundo select mencionado na postagem.

Comment: @Vanderlei aqui tem várias explicações de porque não se deve usar ponto flutuante com dinheiro. Essa é uma premissa básica de qualquer sistema confiável: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro

Comment: @Vanderlei vale notar que em princípio, no manual de afinidades do SQLite o Decimal é convertido para "number", que é armazenado como "integer" se não tiver casas decimais e "float" quando tem. O fato de funcionar com "real", entretanto, não significa que deve ser usado, justamente por causa dos problemas acumulativos de arredondamento em quaisquer operações matemáticas. (muitas vezes você armazena um 23.50, mas o REAL armazena como 23.499999999999.... - na tela aparece certo, mas ao fazer uma multiplicação por quantidade, começa a dar erro, mesmo na tela aparecendo .50)

Comment: E isso não é um problema exclusivo da linguagem A ou B, e sim do jeito que os números flutuantes trabalham. Mais um exemplo, de fora: https://javeiros.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/evite-float-e-double-se-voce-quer-respostas-exatas/ - se pesquisar por "float" e "dinheiro" vai achar bastante coisa sobre o assunto. DBs que tem tipo "decimal" e "money" não usam float internamente, e sim um formato fixo. Como o SQLite não tem isso nativo, precisa adaptar algum tipo dele. Só sobram os inteiros e os textos. O inteiro é mais eficiente e economiza espaço, o texto é mais simples de visualizar.

Comment: De fato usar `real` no SQLite para valor monetário não dá. Para ver sobre o SQLite: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78306/101. Para ver sobre o problema em geral: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101. Isso é algo básico que todo programador que já tem um mínimo de experiência acaba aprendendo. É um problema relacionado ao processador e todas as linguagens e bancos de dados sofrem com ele. A explicação detalhada está nessas perguntas, mas tem diversas outras respostas de vários autores no site, e fora dele. Tem *links* para outras fontes para quem ainda não aprendeu sobre o assunto.

Comment: Estou refatorando de acordo com experiência de vocês. Devo demorar um pouco, já que é um projeto como hobby. Vou armazenar como int, dividir por 100 e apresentar no DGV como string. Seria este o caminho?

Comment: @Vanderlei o importante é entender onde é que o float "trai" as nossas expectativas (o fato de vc ver um 3,50, mas o PC ver 3,4999999982337). O inteiro tem esse trabalho a mais para dividir, mas se largar o arredondamento pro último passo, garante que a imprecisão não vá propagar por vários cálculos.

Comment: Independente da armazenagem, um outro exemplo de cuidado quando fizer cálculos monetários, é sempre manter a precisão escolhida, não deixando "quebrados" a mais. Se por exemplo for vender um produto fracionado cujo cálculo valor x quantidade deu 23,731 centavos, e na tela aparece 23.73 só, você precisa descartar esse 1 a mais no final antes de somar o total (somar 23.73, e não 23.731), senão esse "subcentavo" invisível vai se juntando com outros quebrados de subtotal, e no final o cliente tem uma soma com centavos a mais sem saber de onde veio, queimando a confiabilidade e a contabilidade.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui uma solução com base nas sugestões dos colegas.
Os campos de valores monetários foram criados como INTEGER e eu tratei a formatação decimal toda via código na aplicação. A estrutura da classe que eu criei me permitiu converter os valores no DataTable antes de chegar ao dataGridview da aplicação. Segue a o método principal da classe:

```
public static DataTable dtColumnIntToDecimal(DataTable dt, int column)
    {
        List<decimal> price = new List<decimal>();
        //Gerar lista de valores em decimal
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {                
            decimal aux = Convert.ToDecimal((long)row[column]) / 100;
            price.Add(aux);     
        }

        //clonar o datatable, transformando a coluna em decimal
        DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
        dtCloned.Columns[column].DataType = typeof(decimal);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
        }

        //Inserir valores em decimal
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            dtCloned.Rows[rowIndex][column] = price[rowIndex];
            Console.WriteLine(dtCloned.Rows[rowIndex][column]);
        }

        //atualiza o total de valores (opcional) 
        valorTotal = price.Sum();
        //Retorna o DataTable
        return dtCloned;
    }
```

Código para utilização da classe:

```
//Minha consulta
sql.Select("Produto", tbConsulta.Text);                        
//DataTable retornado
DataTable dt = Util.dtColumnIntToDecimal(sql.Datatable, 2);
//Aplicação do DataTable ao DataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

... e para que o formato de moeda apareça corretamente sem eliminar os zeros após a virgula, basta aplicar o "C2" no DefaultCellStyle.Format na coluna.

Comment: +1, legal. Outro desafio vai ser armazenar datas :) Mas já te adianto que tem 2 formatos bem comuns para isso: integer, se quiser unix time, que é contando em segundos desde 1/1/1970, e real se for usar Pr. Julian Day, que é o número de dias desde 24/11/-4714. No segundo caso, as horas são representadas em float, sendo 0.5 equivalente ao meio-dia. O SQLite tem funções para trabalhar com as duas situações, é o caso de ver qual combina melhor com a linguagem cliente e a aplicação como um todo. Eu gosto mais do unix time por ser inteiro, mas ele não tem milésimos de segundo. Vai da necessidade.