# Arredondamento em resultado de multiplicação

Tags: sql, sql-server, tipagem, cast

Estou com esse seguinte cenário:
 - fazer uma multiplicação de 2 valores que serão arredondados para 2 casas para a tabela que vai ser inserido o seu resultado.

Segue o exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    A DECIMAL(23,6),
    B DECIMAL(28,2)
)
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES (0.002071, 84.50)
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES (0.011500, 50.00)

SELECT *, 
    A * CAST(B AS FLOAT) res_cast,
    ROUND(A * CAST(B AS FLOAT),2) res_cast_round,
    A * B res,
    ROUND(A * B,2) res_round
FROM #TMP
DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Os resultados no SQL Server 2012 são:
[image: Resultado]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos ver, fazendo `cast` no segundo valor para a multiplicação para a primeira conta `0.002071 * 84.50 = 0.1749995`, o resultado e arredondamento nesse caso está OK, resultando em `0.17`. Mas na segunda conta `0.011500 * 50.00 = 0.575`, o arredondamento está errado, resultando em `0.57`.

Então, para resolver o problema da segunda conta basta simplesmente tirar o `cast` no segundo valor: `0.011500 * 50.00 = 0.575000`, o arredondamento está OK, resultando em `0.58`. Mas na primeira conta `0.002071 * 84.50 = 0.175000` já sai com o resultado errado e quando arredondamos o valor `0.18` está OK.

Alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Tente assim `ROUND( CAST(A AS DECIMAL(10,2) * CAST(B AS DECIMAL(10,2), 2) `

Comment: @MarcosRegis se eu fizer um cast no valor de A para 2 casas decimais estarei ignorando valor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problema específico

Como os dados estão sendo armazenados como `DECIMAL` eu entendo que estes são valores monetários ou outro tipo de número que exige exatidão. Então a conta certa está sendo feita com as duas últimas operações. Ou seja, está multiplicando dois números decimais exatos e depois fazendo o mesmo arredondando para 2 casas. Ele arredonda para cima porque este é o comportamento padrão do arredondamento no SQL Server. É possível usar outros critérios. O padrão vai pra cima em números positivos a partir de 5 na casa que deve arredondar. Veja o [artigo na Wikipedia para saber mais sobre arredondamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) ([em português sem detalhes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)).

O critério de arredondamento precisa fazer parte da regra de negócio. E depois desta regra ser bem definida, tem que adequar o código para atendê-la, baseando-se no funcionamento do mecanismo da linguagem que está sendo usada.

Parece estar tudo correto. Como um deles tem 6 casas decimais, e o outro tem 2 casas, o resultado ficou com 3 casas, então houve um arredondamento implícito de 0.1749995 para 0.175. Aí o arredondamento explícito arredondou para 0.18. Ou seja, parece tudo certo.

Consegui uma gambiarra:

```
SELECT *, 
    A * CAST(B AS FLOAT) res_cast,
    ROUND(A * CAST(B AS FLOAT), 2) res_cast_round,
    CAST(A as DECIMAL(10, 6)) * CAST(B as DECIMAL(10, 6)) res,
    ROUND(CAST(A as DECIMAL(10, 6)) * CAST(B as DECIMAL(10, 6)), 2) res_round
FROM TMP
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bc3a/1) (se estiver vivo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Rounding.sql).

## Não pode usar FLOAT

As duas primeiras operações estão erradas por transformar um valor exato em valor aproximado, afinal `FLOAT` é um tipo de dado numérico com parte decimal representada em binário e é impossível representar todos os valores em binário. Este tipo faz contas mais rápidas no processador, mas não consegue ser exato. Para alguns tipos de cálculos a velocidade é mais importante que a exatidão, então ter um número aproximado pode ser considerado correto.

A maioria dos programadores não sabem disto mas é uma das coisas mais importantes que precisam saber. E muitos, mesmo depois de aprender isto, acham que este "pequeno errinho" não importa.

Falo muito sobre isso em outras perguntas:

- [Como converter string para double sem erro de arredondamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77592/101)
- [Matemática precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101)
- [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)

É bom saber tudo isso para não tentar soluções com o tipo errado.