# Problemas com inserção de dados em campo float no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, float

Estou com um problema ao inserir um valor em um campo na tabela, esse campo esta como float(15,6).

Rodei um insert aqui

```
INSERT INTO valores (valor) VALUES ('1160.480000');
```

Por que ele insere o valor como 1160.479980?

Comment: Tira as aspas. Já tentou ?

Comment: Sim, foi uma das primeiras tentativas e continua na mesma

Comment: Você está armazenando isso em um `float`. Use `decimal`. Veja esta resposta no post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106870/arredondamento-em-resultado-de-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o para entender do por quê.

Comment: O certo então é eu alterar o tipo do campo para decimal?

Comment: Essa valor é para guardar valores monetarios?

Comment: Veja esse também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808478/why-does-the-value-of-this-float-change-from-what-it-was-set-to

Comment: @rray vai ser sim. Alterando para DECIMAL vi que resolveu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formalizando a resposta:
O erro acontece porque o [`float`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/floating-point-types.html) não guarda precisões exatas - e sim aproximadas, para isto (valores monetários), devemos utilizar o [`decimal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)...

O decimal no MySQL tem a capacidade de armazenar no máximo 65 dígitos, e desses, 30 dígitos podem ser usados para a casa decimal.

Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106870/arredondamento-em-resultado-de-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) detalha melhor os porquês.
[Outro post sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37947/valor-decimal-mysql?rq=1).

```
ALTER TABLE valores MODIFY valor decimal(15,6);

INSERT INTO valores (valor) VALUES (1160.480000);
```