# Select Float Mysql

Tags: mysql

Num campo `mysql` está armazenado `104.13` em formato `Float`;
Com esse select , consigo ver o registro:

```
SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE valor like '104%';
```

Porém com esse select não aparece:

```
SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE valor = '104.13';
```

Como faço para selecionar valores `FLOAT` ?

Comment: @RBZ assim retornam valores que estão "próximos", não somente o 104.13

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza 0 resultados retornados

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza me parece que o campo é texto, por isso as aspas e a citação na pergunta "*em formato Float*", por isso sem aspas simples não deve funcionar.

Comment: Na verdade, é Float mesmo, mas não consigo selecionar o registro

Comment: Tentou com `ROUND` ? Porque o float pode não estar retornando valor idêntico.

Comment: Se seu campo for texto, pode ser problema de espaços, tentou `WHERE valor like '104.13%'`?

Comment: [B.5.4.8 Problems with Floating-Point Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)

Comment: Se é `float` as aspas são desnecessárias, e a sugestão do @DiegoRafaelSouza deveria funcionar bem

Comment: Tente: `SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE CAST(valor as decimal(5,2)) = 104.13`

Comment: `WHERE valor like '104.13%'` assim funciona, mesmo assim estou estranhando esse comportamento

Comment: assim tbm funciona `SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE CAST(valor as decimal(5,2)) = 104.13`, Mas PQ isso ????

Comment: [Aqui tem uma resposta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37955/78713). A depender de como o registro foi inserido, pode realmente ser o problema do ponto flutuante mencionado pelo @RBZ.

Comment: Realmete @DiegoRafaelSouza, o que o RBZ comentou é verdade, pude comprovar o problema com esse fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69728/9   E só acontece no `MySQL` nos outros DBs funciona

Comment: @RicardoPontual Deve funcionar pode ser por puro acidente. O mesmo problema pode acontecer em outros bancos com outros valores. Acredito que a discrepância esteja relacionada à implementação de baixo nível de cada SGBD ou à arquitetura.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O tipo de dados Float no MySQL é inerentemente impreciso.
Se você estiver planejando usar um tipo de dados **float** para uma coluna em seu banco de dados, **deverá reconsiderar**, especialmente se estiver planejando usá-lo para armazenar valores monetários.

> As tentativas de tratar valores de ponto flutuante como comparações
>   exatas podem causar problemas.
>   Fonte: [B.5.4.8 Problemas com valores de ponto flutuante - Documentação MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)

---

**Algumas formas possíveis**

Convertendo para decimal com `CAST`:

```
SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE CAST(valor as decimal(5,2)) = 104.13
```

Usando o `ROUND`:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ROUND(valor,2) = 104.13
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b3f7b/1)

---

Esse link irá tirar praticamente todas suas dúvidas sobre o uso do **float**:

[Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219774/92908)

Mais alguns:

[MySQL Float](https://leehblue.com/match-a-float-in-mysql/)

[Floating-point arithmetic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37947/valor-decimal-mysql/37952#37952

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176745/problemas-com-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-em-campo-float-no-mysql